# Как добавить виртуальный аргумент graphQl?

Tags: php, graphql

Мне нужно добавить виртуальный аргумент с типом данных boolean .

```
public static function saveCollection()
{
    $arguments = parent::saveCollection();
    $arguments['searh'] = Argument::bool('поиск');

    return $arguments;
}
```

Вот так аргумент добавляется, но вот в таком ввиде

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а мне нужно чтобы Boolean был массивом(searh: [searh: Boolean])

Пробую через метод wraplist

```
public static function saveCollection()
{
    $arguments = parent::saveCollection();
    $arguments['searh'] = Argument::bool('Поиск');

    return parent::wrapList($arguments['searh']);
}
```

но так мой аргумент не выводится

Использую библиотеку webonyx/graphql-php в Laravel

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: @AK Расписал проблему подробнее